# Macro for promoting sections to chapters

Tags: macros, sectioning

I have a document where I would like to "promote" all sections to chapters, all subsections to sections, etc. That should affect not only the table of contents, but the documents as a whole.

For example:

```
\section{Title A}
\subsection{Title B}
\subsubsection{Title C}
```

Should actually be treated as if the document was like this:

```
\chapter{Title A}
\section{Title B}
\subsection{Title C}
```

I searched in this website how to do it, but most of the answers seem to focus on the table of contents. I tried to do it myself by adding the following to my document:

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\chapter{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\section{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
```

However what I get with that is that everything becomes a chapter, as if it is applied recursively. So the result is as if the document was like this:

```
\chapter{Title A}
\chapter{Title B}
\chapter{Title C}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can get what I need with minimal changes to the original tex files (possibly none, since it is a huge document with many sections)?

Thank you!

Comment: First thing coming into my mind is a global search and replace. You could also have a look at package `coseoul`

Comment: `\subsection` is redefined to `\section`, but all `\sections` are also redefined to `\chapter`. That is why you experience the behaviour.

Comment: Yep, that's why I tried to put the `\renewcommand`s in that specific order, hoping that all sections would be changed to chapters in the first sweep, than all subsections to sections, etc without overlap. But thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\subparagraph\paragraph
\let\paragraph\subsubsection
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test section to chapter}
\subsection{Test subsection to section}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection to subsection}
\paragraph{Test paragraph to subsubsection}
\subparagraph{Test subparagraph to paragraph}

\end{document}
```

An image of the document with the `\let` lines commented out:

[image]

An image of the same document with the `\let` lines active:

The ToC:

[image]

and the first page of the body:

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with `\thebibliography`. It uses a macro for top-level section which may be redefined by this approach. For example if the core text uses `\chapter` and `\section` and I change documentclass to article and redefine `\chapter` to `\section` and `\section` to `\subsection` then `\thebibliography` uses `\chapter` which is now redefined to `\section`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to make this action nearly automatic, you could use the `C-c =` option in `reftex` with the `AUCTeX` package. From there, use `>` or `<` to promote or demote the relevant portion of the document. This brings with it the sub-portions of those documents.